# how to limit the number of the markers in Android Google Maps API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

My question refers to the  new Google Maps API v2 in Android.

We can easily get the LatLng(point) on Google Maps, if setting the below;

```
@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

    }
```

And if want to add the marker whenever touching on Google Map, we do the below;

```
@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

        googleMap.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions().
                position(point).
                title("Hello World"));
    }
```

Then we can get both the marker and LatLng(point) where we touch on map.

But the problem is that all markers **DO NOT disappear** whenever touching on map.

**Question 1**: Whenever I touch on map, I want to add just the last marker on map. As you may know, to do this,we can add "googleMap.clear()" before adding "addmarker()" in the code. But does another method exist ?

**Question 2**: When the only one marker exists on map,I want to add just my second marker on map using touching on the maps, "onMapClick". In short, I don't want to add the third marker on the map within "public void onMapClick(LatLng point){}". How?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** Try `googleMap.clear()` before adding new marker.

**Question 2:** Store markers you want to keep in a `List` and add them as needed.

**Edit:**
Well then I would refer you to this question: [How to remove single marker using Google Maps V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702379/how-to-remove-single-marker-using-google-maps-v2)

Comment: Then could you elaborate what I'm missing?

Comment: @Martynas...hahaha,,.so sorry...I don't mean your answer is wrong...Your answer for Q1 is right and what I do know well, but I am looking for another answer. And for Q2, I cannot fully understand what you say. I would like to find my answer in such control statement like "if","for" etc. Your answer is very excellent.

Comment: @Martynas..I updated my question, so sorry I did not explain what I want to query fully.

Comment: @Martynas..Thanks for your comment...you did link a good reference...it helped me....thanks a lot..

Comment: @Martynas..LOL...Still now I am looking for the answer of my question.